# React Navigation Reanimted Task :app:checkDebugAarMetadata FAILED

Tags: react-native, react-navigation-v5, react-native-reanimated

This happend when i run   "npx react-native run-android"

Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
> Failed to transform react-native-reanimated-65-jsc.aar (project :react-native-reanimated) to match attributes {artifactType=android-aar-metadata}.
> > Execution failed for JetifyTransform: C:\Users\USER\Desktop\ReactNative\Project3\node_modules\react-native-reanimated\android\react-native-reanimated-65-jsc.aar

It happend after i install  "npm install react-native-reanimated"
But if i uninstall "react-native-reanimated" my project can run
I don't know how to solve this

After i install reanimated 2.3 alpha3 my project can run, But it has a new problem

BUNDLE ./index.js

error: Error: Unable to resolve module ./Hooks from C:\Users\USER\Desktop\ReactNative\Project3\node_modules\react-native-reanimated\src\reanimated2\index.ts:

None of these files exist:

node_modules\react-native-reanimated\src\reanimated2\Hooks(.native|.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.json|.native.json|.json|.android.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.android.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx)
node_modules\react-native-reanimated\src\reanimated2\Hooks\index(.native|.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.json|.native.json|.json|.android.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.android.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx)

Answer (score 0):

I think the stable version of reanimated still doesn't support react native 0.65, try installing the 2.3 alpha 3

Comment: what is the command that install 2.3 alpha 3, i will try it

Comment: yarn add react-native-reanimated@2.3.0-alpha.3 or npm install react-native-reanimated@2.3.0-alpha.3 depending on what package manager you are using

Answer (score 0):

After i install reanimated 2.3 alpha3 my project can run, But it has a new problem

BUNDLE  ./index.js

error: Error: Unable to resolve module ./Hooks from C:\Users\USER\Desktop\ReactNative\Project3\node_modules\react-native-reanimated\src\reanimated2\index.ts:

None of these files exist:

- node_modules\react-native-reanimated\src\reanimated2\Hooks(.native|.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.json|.native.json|.json|.android.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.android.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx)
- node_modules\react-native-reanimated\src\reanimated2\Hooks\index(.native|.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.json|.native.json|.json|.android.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.android.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx)

Comment: Please edit your question instead of posting additional information as an "answer". The edit link is at the bottom of your question post.